# Set the renderer for a Vaadin 8.1 Grid column?

Tags: datagrid, format, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

In Vaadin 8.1, the [`Grid`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.2/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.html) API doc shows that we can pass a [renderer](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.2/com/vaadin/ui/renderers/AbstractRenderer.html) as part of the [column](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.2/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.Column.html) definition when calling `addColumn`. But I do not see any setter methods for changing the renderer.

Is there any way to change the renderer on a column in the Grid object?

Comment: Do you mean [this method](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.0/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.Column.html#setRenderer-com.vaadin.ui.renderers.Renderer-)? You can get the column object like `grid.getColumn("yourColumnId")`.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich As steffen says, you only have to call the setter like `grid.getColumn(columnId).setRenderer(rendererObject);` Where columnId is an `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

## `Column` rather than `Grid`

Call `setRenderer` on the *column* rather than the grid.

The column is represented by a class nested inside the grid class, [`Grid.Column`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.0/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.Column.html). Pass a column ID to retrieve the particular column.

```
myGrid.getColumn( someColumnId )
```

There you call [`setRenderer`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.0/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.Column.html#setRenderer-com.vaadin.ui.renderers.Renderer-).

```
myGrid.getColumn( someColumnId ).setRenderer( myRenderer ) ;
```

Replacing the renderer is shown in the Vaadin Framework guide, [Grid](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html) page, section [Column Renderers](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html#components.grid.renderer).